# My Jupyter Notebook added two linebreaks in some of my comments, deleting some parts and thus breaking execution

Tags: jupyter-notebook, formatting, comments, jupyter-lab

I use Jupyter lab and today when I tried executing my notebook I ran into errors caused by some of the comments beeing splitted and moved to the next line.

I did not run any formatters on the notebook.

Has someone experienced this behaviour before?

Before:

```
#making df_articles_categories_wanted only contain articleIDs that are in the
#categories that are wanted, in case all leafs from the English and German Shop [missing]
```

After:

```
#making df_articles_categories_wanted 

 only contain articleIDs that are in the

#categories that are wanted, in 

 case all leafs from the English and German Shop
```